# Using fileinput to operate on a list of filenames

Tags: python

I'm writing a function to read the error logs in a directory, and print the specific cause of the error (Marked by a line beginning with Error:). In theory, there could be hundreds of error files, so I need to open, read and filter hundreds of files. Fileinput seemed to be the correct module to use in this instance, but it only seems to work on one file despite me knowing that it should process multiple times, I'm wondering if there's something up with my code, pretty new to python.

Background, I os.walked the directory I'm looking for, and put the path of all the error logs into a list, now I want to go through the list, open each file in the list (since list item is file paths) and then go inside them line for line and extract the error message.

Code:

```
for item in failures: 
    for line in fileinput.input(item):
        if re.match('Error:', line):
            print line
```

The output is successful, but it prints the output of one file many times, instead of the output of all the unique items in my list.

Comment: what is in your failures list?

Answer (score 0):

"To specify an alternative list of filenames, pass it as the first argument to input()."
https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html

Provide the list instead of a single file.
You don't need the outer for loop.

Alan Isaac

Comment: I agree.  I suspect "failures" was incorrectly constructed.

Comment: there must only be one element or a repeated element